# How to return a number OR error if any in async function?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to get the result from an async function but that async function can return either number or Error(if thrown by our code) in promise.

I tried to throw an exception from the catch block. But that I am getting some TSLint error that Expression Expected.

```
private async insertAppOrg(orgId): Promise<number> {
    try {
       return this.dbInstance.AppOrg.find({where: {orgId: orgId}})
            .then(async (appOrgData) => {
                if (appOrgData) {
                    return appOrgData.appOrgId;
                } else {
                    return (await this.createAppOrg(orgId)); //return number 
                }
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        return throw new ErrorFactory.DatabaseError(ex);
    }
}
```

This function should return orgId(number) in case of success, else it should throw an Exception from the catch block.

Comment: At very least, your function doesn't return anything

Comment: is it a member of any class or module?

Comment: Yes, it is the member of a class and am using it in the same class.

Comment: @bambam it will return an promise of number in case of success and thow an error if any.

Comment: no, it doesn't. to return you need the  `return` keyword. You're returning from some inner function, not from `insertAppOrg` though

Comment: Ohh Yes that I correted now.

Answer (score 2):

`return throw` is syntax error because `throw` is a statement, not an expression.

Another problem is that an error from returned promise won't be handled with `try..catch` in `async..await`, it should be:

```
 return await this.dbInstance.AppOrg.find(...).then(...)
```

There's no need to use `then` in `async` function because `await` is syntactic sugar for `then`:

```
private async insertAppOrg(orgId): Promise<number> {
    try {
       const appOrgData = await this.dbInstance.AppOrg.find({where: {orgId: orgId}});
        if (appOrgData) {
            return appOrgData.appOrgId;
        } else {
            return (await this.createAppOrg(orgId));
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        throw new ErrorFactory.DatabaseError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Prasanna There is a point, and the reason was explained. You won't be able to catch a rejection with `try..catch` without `await`.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.
But I have another doubt here, what I will get in appOrgData constant?
according to me, it may return result or error. in both cases, I will get some data. So will it go in else block ever?

Comment: @ManishJoshi I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. You will get the result in appOrgData . It depends on your DB what kind of result it is. In case there was an error, it will go straight to `catch`.

Comment: @estus in the above post dont work properly because of this.dbInstance.AppOrg.find() is sequalize function and it's not async so if I put the await it won't work. any workaround for this?

Comment: @ManishJoshi There's no need for a workaround. It can be `await`ed. In order to work, it should return a promise. Sequelize uses promises for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise, and remove the try-catch block.

```
private async insertAppOrg(orgId: number): Promise<number> {
  return this.dbInstance.AppOrg.find({ where: { orgId: orgId } })
      .then(async (appOrgData: any) => {
        if (appOrgData) {
          return appOrgData.appOrgId;
        } else {
          return (await this.createAppOrg(orgId));
        }
      })
      .catch((e: any) => {
        throw new Error("This is an error")
      });
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but in this case, IDE(TSLint) is saying  "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value"